# Is it possible to retrieve a name along with min and max in a column, grouped by another column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mamp

Horribly written title aside, here is what i want to do. I have a table that looks kind of like this:

| ID | Name | Title | Departement | Some Integer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | Manager | 3 | 42 |
| 2 | Charles | ShiftMgr | 3 | 56 |
| 3 | Jane | Employee | 4 | 23 |
| 4 | Skippy | Manager | 4 | 36 |
| 5 | Miles | ShiftMgr | 3 | 85 |
| 6 | Jenna | Employee | 5 | 54 |

Now, I want to be able to obtain the Highest **and** the Lowest from *Some Integer* grouped by Departement. So far I've done this with:

```
SELECT Departement, MAX(SomeInteger), MIN(SomeInteger) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Departement;
```

Which returns exactly that, departement and the lowest and highest. However I would like to see the names of both the highest and lowest from each departement.
My best guess was:

```
SELECT Departement, Name, SomeInteger FROM Table 
WHERE (SomeInteger = (SELECT MAX(SomeInteger) FROM Table) OR SomeInteger = (SELECT MIN(SomeInteger) FROM Table)) 
GROUP BY Departement;
```

However I have not had much luck. I would paste all the other attempts but whatever I try I get some sort of error.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What version of MySql? The answer her changes drastically if you're still on MySql 5.7 or older vs 8.0 or newer, because if 8.0's support for window functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table t1
JOIN ( SELECT Departement, MIN(SomeInteger) mini, MAX(SomeInteger) maxi
       FROM Table 
       GROUP BY Departement ) t2 USING ( Departement )
WHERE t1.SomeInteger IN (t2.mini, t2.maxi)
```

If more than one row have the same highest/lowest value then all of them will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the windows function:

- Here I am assuming you have a column named salary and you need a name per department with the highest and lowest salary.
- `First_Value` allows you to pick the first value based on order and aggregation level i.e similar to `group by` clause
- For the highest salary the order by is `DESC` for the lowest one it is `ASC`

```
    SELECT 
    Distinct
    Departement, 
    MAX(SomeInteger) over(partition by department), 
    MIN(SomeInteger) over(partition by department),
    first_value(name) over(partition by department order by salary) as name_with_lowest_salary_in_each_department,
    first_value(name) over(partition by department order by salary desc) as name_with_highest_salary_in_each_department
    
    FROM Table ;
```

Comment: I believe it would work since order by is specified and the department name is in the parition by

Comment: yes you are right should work with ` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`. To keep things simple i will remove the code 2